# Vmware: Mounting guest XP drive in windows 10 host

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, file-sharing

How can I share guest OS files / folders and access them on Host machine?
Host = Windows 10 Enterprise
Guest = Windows XP.
I tried numerous guides online but nothing worked. Both machines can ping each other.
Can any one point me to any article or tool to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set up a network share on the guest machine (right-click a folder in Windows Explorer and choose "Sharing"). You may need to adjust the guest machine's firewall settings.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that but Windows 10 is not showing shares.

Comment: It would be better to ask this question on superuser.com.

Comment: Check if your win10 got the september update, this update disable the SMBv1 and winXP support only SMBv1 there for winXP cannot connect to win10 using file sharing (SMB protocol)